# Multiply differential operator matrix and shape function matrix

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, finite-element-method

I'm new to *Mathematica*.

Say $N(\xi, \eta)$ (`NSHAPE` in code below) is a 2x6 matrix:

$$
N(\xi,\eta) = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 -\xi -\eta & 0 & \xi  & 0 & \eta  & 0 \\
 0 & 1 -\xi -\eta & 0 & \xi  & 0 & \eta  \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

I wanna get a 4x6 matrix

$$
Q=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\partial }{\partial \xi } & 0 \\
 \frac{\partial }{\partial \eta } & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{\partial }{\partial \xi } \\
 0 & \frac{\partial }{\partial \eta } \\
\end{array}
\right]
N(\xi, \eta)
$$

I tried

```
NSHAPE = {{1 - ξ - η, 0, ξ, 0, η, 0}, {0, 1 - ξ - η, 0, ξ, 0, η}};
Q = Map[D[#1, #2] &, {NSHAPE, {ξ, η}}]
```

but it doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: Please show us `NSHAPE` in valid _Mathematica_ code.

Comment: Something like this? ```Clear[e, n, matN, matD];

matN[e_, n_] :=
  {
   {1 - e - n, 0, e, 0, n, 0},
   {0, 1 - e - n, 0, e, 0, n}
   };

matD = {
   {D[#, e] &, 0},
   {D[#, n] &, 0},
   {0, D[#, e] &},
   {0, D[#, n] &} 
   };

matD . matN[e, n] // MatrixForm  ```

Comment: Since Syed has done you a favor, I added the missing `NSHAPE` for you. Do remember complete code sample is almost always necessary for an on-topic question in this site.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much!  The NSHAPE in code is actually N(xi, eta) mat in my description, because N is a function name in Mathematica, so I replaced the name.

Answer (score 6):

One can use [`Inner`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html) like this:

```
mydot[a_, b_] := Inner[If[Head[#1] === Function, #1[#2], #1*#2] &, a, b, Plus];
```

This multiplies `a` and `b` as matrices, but if an entry of `a` is a function, it will apply the function.

Example:

```
mydot[{{1/# &, 3}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}]
(* {{1/a + 3 c, 1/b + 3 d}} *)
```

Comment: One could also use `Inner` with `Construct` if there are only functions in the matrix on the left. For both cases of function application and multiplication another possibility is  `mydot[a_, b_] := 
 Inner[Switch[#1, _Function, Construct[##], _, Times[##]] &, a, b, Plus]`

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about `Construct`, I must have typed `#1[#2]&` a million times in my life so far.

Comment: #1[#2] is faster to type or about the same speed as `Construct[##]` (with autocompletion) but `Construct` is nice when no `Slot` is needed as in the case where the left matrix elements are functions (so without the `If` testing) as it's just `Inner[Construct,a,b,Plus]`. Your answer is the only case where I found it could be useful.

Comment: Actually, `Inner[Construct, a, b]` since `Plus` is assumed when it is not included.

Answer (score 5):

```
nmat[ξ_, η_] := {{1 - ξ - η, 0, ξ, 0, η, 
   0}, {0, 1 - ξ - η, 0, ξ, 0, η}}

opmat = {{D[#, ξ] &, 0}, {D[#, η] &, 0}, {0, 
   D[#, ξ] &}, {0, D[#, η] &}}

    opmat . nmat[ξ, η] /. Times[a_, b_Function] :> Composition[b][a]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

Just combine 5th syntax of `D` and 4th syntax of `Flatten` in the document:

```
Flatten[D[NSHAPE, {{ξ, η}}], {{1, 3}, {2}}]
(* {{-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
    {0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1}} *)
```

If you prefer the differential operator method shown in traditional math formula, make use of `UpSetDelayed` (`^:=`):

```
d[x_] expr_ ^:= D[expr, x]
{{d[ξ], 0}, {d[η], 0}, {0, d[ξ]}, {0, d[η]}} . NSHAPE
(* {{-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
    {0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1}} *)
```