# Differential operator not working

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Could someone help me understand why this code does not work?

[image]

I paste the code here but I am unable to format it:

```
PacletInstall["https://github.com/carlwoll/DifferentialOperator/releases/download/0.1/DifferentialOperator-0.0.1.paclet"]
```

(*$Failed*)

```
PacletUninstall
```

(*PacletUninstall*)

```
PacletInstall[ForceVersionInstall -> True]
```

(*PacletInstall[ForceVersionInstall -> True]*)

```
    ( {
   {Subscript[\[PartialD], x], 0},
   {0, Subscript[\[PartialD], x]}
  } ) . ( {
   {x^2},
   {E^ax}
  } )
```

I have tried the following:

[image]

But this does not apply the operators to the right hand side matrix

Comment: Have you tried to follow the first warning and re-install the package, and then `Get` that package?

Comment: Yes, I have run PacletUninstall as well as PacletInstall[ForceVersionInstall -> True] and still doesn't work

Comment: I'm not familiar with his package, but with `Subscript[\[PartialD], x]` replaced by `DifferentialOperator[x]`, I get `{{x^2 Subscript[\[PartialD], x]},{E^ax Subscript[\[PartialD], x]}}`. Is this what you expect?

Comment: Helpful, but not quite what I need. I would need the operator to be applied to the elements of the second matrix. I will update the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the corresponding examples for the package shown in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162590/1871) carefully, you'll notice the operator created by the package and the expression to be differentiated isn't *linked* by `Times`, but `Construct` i.e. code like

```
L = DifferentialOperator[x];
L@Exp[a x]
```

will *work*, but

```
L = DifferentialOperator[x];
L Exp[a x]
```

won't. This design is reasonable, because `Times` is commutative, but differential operator is not. `Dot` (`.`) evaluates to combination of `Times` and `Plus` so `DifferentialOperator` won't work in it, either.

To fix the code, we can use `Inner` as shown in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4767/1871) and [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274971/1871):

```
Inner[If[FreeQ[#1, DifferentialOperator], Times[##], Construct[##]] &,
      {{DifferentialOperator[x], 0}, 
       {0, DifferentialOperator[x]}}, 
      {x^2, Exp[a x]}]

(* {2 x, a E^(a x)} *)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I am totally confused though. I still don't obtain your result. My output is {DifferentialOperator[x][x^2], DifferentialOperator[x][E^(a x)]}

Comment: @nc520 Sounds like you haven't loaded the package. Have you executed `<<DifferentialOperator\``?

Comment: Thanks it worked. Excellent answer